# what's externalContext.requestParameterMap['gateway'] mean in login-webflow.xml

Tags: cas

CAS config file , login-webflow.xml, i see

```
<decision-state id="gatewayRequestCheck">
    <if test="externalContext.requestParameterMap['gateway'] neq '' &amp;&amp; externalContext.requestParameterMap['gateway'] neq null &amp;&amp; flowScope.service neq null"
    then="gatewayServicesManagementCheck" else="viewLoginForm" />
</decision-state>
```

who can tell me what's the mean of `externalContext.requestParameterMap['gateway']` ?

Answer (score 1):

This refers to the gateway parameter that is part of the CAS protocol [1]. Basically, it checks to see if the parameter is defined in the incoming request and if so, switches to a different state.

> gateway [OPTIONAL] - if this parameter is set, CAS will not ask the
>   client for credentials. If the client has a pre-existing single
>   sign-on session with CAS, or if a single sign-on session can be
>   established through non-interactive means (i.e. trust authentication),
>   CAS MAY redirect the client to the URL specified by the "service"
>   parameter, appending a valid service ticket. (CAS also MAY interpose
>   an advisory page informing the client that a CAS authentication has
>   taken place.) If the client does not have a single sign-on session
>   with CAS, and a non-interactive authentication cannot be established,
>   CAS MUST redirect the client to the URL specified by the "service"
>   parameter with no "ticket" parameter appended to the URL.

[1] https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/protocol/CAS-Protocol-V2-Specification.html#211-parameters